# Run background.js after performing operations in options.js of chrome extension manifest v3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

In my extension to add custom context menu, the user defines custom context menu entries in options.html (through options.js). The entries are stored `chrome.storage.local`. The background.js reads these entries and creates custom context menu entries.

Once, the user saves new entry for custom context menu, the background.js which is responsible for adding custom context menu entries doesn't get run. Currently the user has to manually update the extension, so the background.js runs again and creates custom context menu with newly added entries.

There were two relevant questions in SOF:

1. [Chrome extension options.js notify content_script.js of settings change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765434/chrome-extension-options-js-notify-content-script-js-of-settings-change)
2. [How can I run background script dynamically in chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38280440/how-can-i-run-background-script-dynamically-in-chrome-extension)

But, these questions were either not directly related or asked during MV2 timeline.

Is there a way we can trigger the execution of background.js based on an action in options.js?

---

Update:

Following solution of invoking background.js script function using onChange event on chrome.storage didn't work:

```
chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function(changes, namespace) {
  for (key in changes) {
    var storageChange = changes[key];
    console.log('Storage key "%s" in namespace "%s" changed. ' +
                'Old value was "%s", new value is "%s".',
                key,
                namespace,
                storageChange.oldValue,
                storageChange.newValue);
    // Create context menu
    createContextMenu();
  }
});
```

Above though console.log prints the output, the createContextMenu seems to be not getting invoked.

Comment: Either send a message from the options script or use chrome.storage.onChanged in the background script.

Comment: Thank you @wOxxOm for the quick response. Should i do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14766302/364474), or should i use `chrome.runtime.reload();`?

Comment: Yes. No reload.

Comment: Thank you @wOxxOm, i will try this solution.

Comment: @wOxxOm though the background.js gets invoked during change in storage, the function to create context menu doesn't get invoked. I have updated the question for the suggested solution.

Comment: Use devtools to debug your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242267/discussion-between-learningloop-and-woxxom).